# How to user use EF Command Interceptor to save data to database when intercepted command is inside transaction

Tags: entity-framework, transactions, interceptor

I'm using EF Command Interceptor to save some data to database after command execution.
(I have some filters to only run this on the commands I want, so it doesn't turn into an infinite loop)

```
    class EFCommandInterceptor : IDbCommandInterceptor
    {
        public void ReaderExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
        {
            var log = new LogModel
            {
                DateTime = DateTime.Now,
                Log = "Log"
            };

            using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                context.Logs.Add(log);
                var res = context.SaveChangesAsync().Result;
            }
        }
    }
```

This works fine most of the time. But If I have any commands that I need to log that are inside a transaction

```
using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope())
{
    // Some commands to intercept
}
```

I get an error on the

> var res = context.SaveChangesAsync().Result;

```
Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out
```

I've tried extending both the connection timeout and the command timeout timers but than it just takes longer to throw the same error.

I've also tried creating a new sql connection and a command in the interceptor but get the same error.

Is there a way to save data to the database in the EF Command Interceptor when it intercepts a command from inside a transaction?

If not is there a way for the Interceptor to ignore commands that are inside transactions?

Answer (score 0):

In general it's better to use a separate logging framework for logging, like log4net, NLog or Serilog, because these loggers log in their own threads and should be insensible to ambient transactions.

A quick test using [Serilog](https://github.com/serilog/serilog) under .Net core 5 shows that it logs even when called within a `TransactionScope`, with async flow enabled, that is rolled back:

```cs
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Events;
using Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer;
using System.Transactions;

using var ts = new TransactionScope(asyncFlowOption: TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled);

var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo
    .MSSqlServer(
        connectionString: @"Server=.\sqlserver;Database=Test;Integrated Security=SSPI;",
        sinkOptions: new MSSqlServerSinkOptions { TableName = "Logs" })
    .CreateLogger();
logger.Information("info");

ts.Dispose(); // Rolls back. Added for clarity. Dispose happens anyway.
```

Each run neatly writes a logging record into the test database.

Here, `Logs` is the standard logging table Serilog expects when nothing else is configured:

```
CREATE TABLE [Logs] (

   [Id] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   [Message] nvarchar(max) NULL,
   [MessageTemplate] nvarchar(max) NULL,
   [Level] nvarchar(128) NULL,
   [TimeStamp] datetime NOT NULL,
   [Exception] nvarchar(max) NULL,
   [Properties] nvarchar(max) NULL

   CONSTRAINT [PK_Logs] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC) 
);
```

Note that Serilog recommends using a static logger object.